# Redraw text on zoomed UIImageView after zooming

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview, zooming

I have an iOS app which boils down to the following:

- A view controller which implements all the `UIScrollViewDelegate` methods.
- A customised `UIImageView` which is the view returned by `viewForZoomingInScrollView` in the first view controller.

In the `drawRect` method of the customised `UIImageView` I overlay some text at various positions on the image, the text can be at various sizes and angles, constrained by a rectangle defined by points on the image. So the co-ordinate system is all relative to the image associated with the `UIImageView`.

Sometimes the text is having to be rendered into areas that are far too small to allow the text to be readable at the default zoom level.

When I zoom in, however, this doesn't make the text any more readable as the text was rendered on the original `UIImageView` at the font size appropriate for the bounds it was given.

What I'd like is some way to redraw this text, in the correct location still, at a proportionally larger font size when zoomed in.  Is this possible, and how would I do it?

Answer (score 2):

I've been working on a zoomable floorplan myself and dealt with it in a rather simple way.

I put my text in labels and put those labels on top of the ImageView.
While zooming the labels scale with the UIImageView and thus the text within scale as well.

When zooming in too much however text becomes vague and blurry so you might want to update those text labels in the:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view atScale:(float)scale
```

For me this was sufficient, I hope this might be so for you as well.

Comment: I've changed my drawing method to use UILabels instead - but it's just as blurry with them, can you enlighten me what you did in the `- (void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view atScale:(float)scale` method which un-blurred them?

Comment: a setNeedsDisplay on all your labels should suffice

Comment: No dice!  I dutifully called `setNeedsDisplay` on each of the labels and they don't change appearance at all - is there some other step that you've assumed I've done?  My `UILabel`s are added to the view which has been zoomed, not the `UIScrollView`. I then `setNeedsDisplay` on each of them after finishing my zoom manoeuvre.

Comment: Strange, have you tried redrawing the imageView? Could you post an image of your actual blur and the scale it was drawn at?

Comment: You can try this as well. Use an enormous fontsize, make the label adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth. I haven't used this in my code but it's worth a shot i suppose, since I'm not certain why ur code doesn't work.

Comment: @MattFellows: I found my code again this evening and what I did was I drew the text again but changed the fontsize with the scale I was in. So in the setNeedsDisplay I redrew the Labels with fontsize: size*scale. This should do the trick for you too. I'm sorry for inconvenience, needed to find my old code ;)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of trying to fix this, I'd say your design is a bit wrong. I'd reengineer this so that you're rendering the entire contents that you're displaying in the highest zoom that you want, and then allow the scrollview to zoom in/out of the finished content by specifying the zoom parameters. Otherwise you'll go insane trying to fix text. Just draw the entire image / document as big as you want it to be, then add THOSE contents to the scroll view, at some lower zoom, allowing the user to zoom in/out as they desire. Then you're done.

Answer (score 2):

You can write your overlay text on UILabels, attached to the UIViewController view.
Then you need to make your own custom class from UIScrollView and override

```
- (void)setContentOffset:(CGPoint)anOffset
```

here, using the anOffset and self.zoomScale you can place your labels at the places you want, with apropriate font size and all. So, they will change their positions every time your scrollview moves or zooms.